# Как изменить цвет текста в Label (TextBlock)?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Как изменить цвет текста в Label (TextBlock)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.label.aspx).

Чтобы просто задать из разметки

```
<Label Background="Black" Foreground="White" />
```

Чтобы менять в процессе из разметки

```
<Label Background="{Binding Background}" Foreground="{Binding Foreground}" />
```

где, например, Background

```
    private string _background;
    public string Background
    {
        get
        {
            return _background;
        }

        set
        {
            _background = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Background");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Background стоит бы сделать не строковым свойством, а Brush.

Answer (score 0):

В коде меняю вот так

```
LabelName.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
```

Comment: А почему не через Binding?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: LabelName.Foreground = Brushes.Black; Что тут не ясного? Просто в коде C# вставляем - и текст в лейбл меняет свой цвет. Сам искал этот вопрос - все почему то отсылают в разметку.